# cakephp save update data from old data value + new value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I don't know the keyword to search with my problem. How to save update data of a field that already exist a value and I want to update it with additional value.

Here is an example cakephp :

```
$userData = array(
      'id' => $userId,
      'credit' => $newCredit // This will update only new credit
);
$this->User->save($userData);
```

If I use the normal query MySQL it would be like this :

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `credit` = `credit` + '$newCredit' WHERE `id` = '$userId'");
```

You can see the normal SQL Query only one time to update with existing data of `credit`. I know I can do by use `SELECT` those data and do the operation in `php`, then `UPDATE` data back, but it'll be 2 times (SELECT, then UPDATE).

So can cakephp can do it at once? and how :D?

Answer (score 2):

[updateAll](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-array-conditions) will work

```
$this->User->updateAll(
       array('credit' => "credit + $newCredit"),
       array('id' => $userId)
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this......

```
   $user =  $this->User->read(null, $primary_key_id);
   $new_credit = $user['User']['credit'] + $add_new_value_of_credit;
   $this->User->id = $primary_key_id;
   $this->User->saveField('credit', $new_credit);
```

Comment: I want my old data in the field named `credit` to update with new credit without replace the old value with the new value.

Comment: you just need to update the "credit" column for respective row right?

Comment: yes, but i want a query to update but without replace my old data value. example I have credit = `10`, then I have another new credit `5` to update, then my credit will be `15` (not `5`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$userData = array(
      'id' => $userId,
      'credit' => 'credit +'.$newCredit // old credit value + new credit value
);
$this->User->save($userData);
```

Or this:

```
$newCredit = 566;
$this->User->read(null, $userId);
$this->User->set('credit',$this->User->field('credit') + $newCredit);
$this->User->save();
```

Comment: No it's not working, the error come out : `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'credit + 1' for column 'credit' at row 1`. with this sql log : `UPDATE users SET credit = 'credit + 5' WHERE id = '120'`. because the `'credit + '.$newCredit` will be convert as string

Comment: when you use `$this->User->read(null, $userId);` it means the select query has been used and then it update the data. so it's the same as I complain above -_-

Comment: That won't work, and if you make it work calling save it won't be an atomic operation.